# Does someone had a problem while checking in git ( git status ) and had a error like this?

Tags: git, git-bash

Why while trying to test my repositories, and typing `git status` it gives me this reply:

```
  .VirtualBox/
    .bash_history
    .git-for-windows-updater
    .gitconfig
    .idlerc/
    .lesshst
    .vscode/
    3D Objects/
    AppData/
    Contacts/
    Downloads/
    Favorites/
    Links/
    Moon/
    Moonlight/
    Music/
    NTUSER.DAT
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e87-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e87-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e87-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e87-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TxR.blf
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
    NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
    OneDrive/
    PycharmProjects/
    Saved Games/
    Searches/
    Videos/
    VirtualBox VMs/
    ntuser.dat.LOG1
    ntuser.dat.LOG2
    ntuser.ini
    php
    test/
```

I also tried running `git add .` and it gives the same output.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error, it looks like a list of files and directories in your home directory. Is that the **exact and only** output you get, or is there any additional text?

Comment: I guess these are all your staged files for commit and you should git init only on your project root folders like androidstudioprojects or anything else not in users directory it will push all of your files to remite repo which have been listed

Comment: Yes , but it was okay till the last time i was checking , like only files that i am working with was output not the all directories in my user path..

Comment: If you didnt made any changes and want to match git local branch with remote branch then try 'git fetch' and then 'git reset --hard origin/yourBranchName' it will match all changes with remote branch, but be cautious do this only if you have no changes in your current working local branch

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma not sure that would help here

Comment: i have nothing in my files...it's my second day while learning git ...

Comment: Please may you look for a hidden `.git` folder in the same folder that contains `.VirtualBox`?

Comment: is there any problem with the path directories ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no man there isn't something like that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something initialized a repo in your userprofile on windows. You may have executed `git init` in the wrong terminal window or folder.

Comment: how to set it up step by step ?

Comment: warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
On branch master

No commits yet

Answer (score 0):

Either you must have git init in wrong directory than your root project as mentioned by jessehouwing or your git files are corrupt

**do this only after taking proper backup of your current project by moving or copying to another location,**

1. Now what you can do is try deleting your `.git` files from earlier where you  might have initiated the git by `git init` command and then again properly re-initiate git with `git init` from your desired root project,
2. Next run  `git add .`
3. Now to check whether desired files are staged for commit run  `git status` it will list all the files which are staged for commit
4. then commit your message by firing this `git commit -m "message here for commit"`
5. To push your local repository to remote branch you nee to run below two commands from your desired root project directory,

```
git remote add origin 'your commit message'
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: `backup of your current project` means copying the `.git` folder somewhere else

Comment: no not only `.git` files but entire project directory  just to make sure you dont lose your working directory otherwise it will be messed up

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma i think i messed up... I tried everything , the thigs i dont know and the things i know,so after all im still in the same position It says Warning: could not open the directory : "bla bla" permission denied...So i think that i cant move the directory ieather delete it...I tried to clone a repo and delete the old repo so i can make a new but doesnt work...I need a professional suggest with this things i dont now how to go after this i dont want to be stuck here -_-